# Cwd em Grunt + Babel

Tags: javascript, grunt, babel

Fala pessoal,
Estou utilizando grunt + babel para compilar meu código, acontece que minhas pastas estão organizadas da seguinte maneira:

```
- pasta1
    - amd
        -src 
            - arquivo.js
- pasta2
     - amd
         -src 
            - arquivo.js
- pasta3
  -subpasta3
      - amd 
         - src
            -arquivo.js
```

E eu só consigo usar o babel de uma forma muito específico, por exemplo:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    babel: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: false,
        presets: ['env']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: './pasta1/amd/src', // aqui so especifico a pasta1
          src: ['*.js'],
          dest: '.pasta1/amd/babel/' // aqui so especifico a pasta1
        }]
      }
    }
```

Eu queria que ele rodasse em todas as pastas amd/src e gerasse dentro da propria pasta amd/ os arquivos compilados pelo babel, já tentei o seguinte:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    babel: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: false,
        presets: ['env']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '**/amd/src',  
          src: ['*.js'],
          dest: '**/amd/babel/' 
        }]
      }
    }
```

**CWD**: Não sei porque nao funciona, a ideia era pegar todas as pastas que contem as pastas amd/src e tornar isso a base

**DEST**:  nessa parte eu não faço ideia de como deixar o dest (pasta babel/ gerada) exatamente dentro da pasta que está o src, por exemplo... dentro de pasta1/src criar a pasta babel/ com todos arquivos .js compilados da pasta1, dentro de pasta2/src criar a pasta babel/ com tds arquivos .js compilados da pasta2

Comment: Renan, a segunda idéia - isso é, colocar os código gerado pelo Babel dentro de uma subpasta do `src` que você está transpilando provavelmente não é uma boa idéia. Transpilar para uma pasta `lib` ou `dist` vai te poupar muita dor de cabeça com O Babel e demais ferramentas de Build.

Comment: Não funciona adicionando ./ ? Ex: cwd: './**/amd/src' e dest: './**/amd/babel/'

Comment: Então anthony, escrevi errado kk, tenho varios plugins (varias pastas) sendo que cada pasta contem as pastas amd/ e src/... eu queria que em cada pasta amd/ (que está em diversas outras pastas de plugins) gerasse o build do babel... ficando mais ou menos assim amd/ ->  src/ e build/

Comment: Gleidson, já testei assim, também não foi :/